# Visualizing very near vertices at any distance

Tags: vertices

I'm searching a way to visualize very near vertices without having to zoom in and searching for them. It seems that if I'm far away from the model the mass of vertex is shown as one.
Is there a convenient way to know that there are multiple vertices in one point even at large distance from the model?
Maybe I'm missing a more convenient practice to clean mashes that have too many vertex, like merging by distance, but even so it could be useful to view vertices when there many. I'm using Blender 2.8.

Comment: Maybe enabling the "statistics" option in "viewport overlays"  might help.  Sometimes this can help identify the number of vertices when some are overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python script

when in edit mode, run this script - it will hide all vertices that **don't** have another vertex nearby.

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C
from collections import defaultdict

me = C.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

grid_subdivisions = 1000  # decrease for more tolerance - more vertices left visible

grid = defaultdict(list)

for v in bm.verts:
    grid[tuple(map(round, v.co*grid_subdivisions))].append(v)
    v.select = False

r = range(-1, 2)
offsets = [(x, y, z) for x in r for y in r for z in r if not x==y==z==0]
for (x, y, z), cell in grid.items():
    if len(cell) == 1 and not any((x+a, y+b, z+c) in grid for a, b, c in offsets):
        cell[0].select = True

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
bpy.ops.mesh.hide()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer better to my question.

Comment: I love this answer...although i don't understand the result with suzanne...and i created a plane to check like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oghge.png and as you can see i moved the one vertex near the other...but if i try your code with that...no vertex is selected/unselected. So obviously i am doing something wrong? what's my mistake? what didn't i understand?

Comment: @Chris The script multiplies each X,Y,Z of each vertex by `grid_subdivisions`, and then rounds them, to create a `(x, y, z)` tuple denoting a grid cell to be used as a key in a dictionary. Without multiplying, in case of Susanne, you would only get 3 possible values for each axis: `-1`, `0`, `1`, due to rounding. Then for each such cell in a grid, 26 surrounding grid cells are checked - if no such neighboring cell is found in the dictionary, it means there's no neighboring populated cells, and if also current cell has only one vertex, it's a sad, alone vertex - and is marked to be hidden.

Comment: @Chris so in your case perhaps the `grid_subdivisions` is too high, and grid cells are small enough that there is no vertex for which other vertices can be found in the same grid cell or no neighboring cell is "populated".

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I am very happy that you don't answer "learn first the basics" like some others do that here. Thank you!! it worked!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can enable Scene Statistics (Preferences->Interface->Status Bar) and then do a circle select with a very small circle radius around the place which is likely to have multiple vertices. Then check in the status bar how many vertices are selected.
[image]

Comment: Stqtus Bar menu doesn't seems to be there in Blender 2.8

Comment: In 2.8 the status bar is displayed by default if I am not mistaken. So no need to enable it.

Comment: that's right, number of vertices are in the bottom of the screen